# Integral related to fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

Let the Fourier transform of a function and its inverse be given as:

$$\mathcal{F}[f](\lambda) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-i\lambda t} dt$$

$$f(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathcal{F}[f](\lambda)e^{i\lambda t} d\lambda$$

I wish to compute the following integral for $a,b>0$:

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(a^2+x^2)(b^2+x^2)} dx$$

I know that the fourier transform of the function $\psi_a:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\quad \psi_a(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{2a}{a^2+t^2}$ is $\mathcal{F}[\psi_a](\lambda) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-a|\lambda|}$. I have also shown using the convolution theorem that $\psi_{a+b} = \psi_a * \psi_b$, where $*$ denotes convolution.

The integral $I$ looks similar to $\psi_a\psi_b$ without the constants in the denominator. Can this somehow be used to solve the integral?

Comment: First, solving an integral doesn't make sense. Moreover, what is the connection between the Fourier transform of anything and the integral you wish to compute ? You can compute your integral just by doing a [partial fractional decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Procedure)

Comment: Isn’t your integral just $\psi_a * \psi_b(0)$?

Comment: You can also apply the Plancherel theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem , which states $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g^{*}(x)dx =\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat f(\lambda)\hat g^{*}(\lambda)d\lambda$

Comment: Partials fractions can decompose the integral into terms you can recognize.